# D3 Add Tooltip to Stacked Area Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to add tooltip on mouseover event for the below stacked area chart:

https://observablehq.com/@d3/stacked-area-chart?collection=@d3/d3-shape

The tooltip should contain current mouse position's graph type (e.g. Wholesale and Retail Trade), x position (e.g. year 2001) and y position (e.g. 500).

I tried getting data for mouseover event however it includes all data range of y-axis of current graph type (e.g. Wholesale and Retail Trade). I tried searching online for various examples but could not find a matching example. Has anyone created similar tooltip on stacked area chart?

I have created the below sample chart to demonstrate the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/3gqf8x5d/

Mouseover event code:

```
d3.selectAll("path")
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  })
```

Comment: Can you edit the post with the code you tried?

Comment: @Shashank - I have added a sample chart to replicate the issue.